# Do something after all FB API calls finish

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have some functions that are making some Facebook API calls, and an init one:

```
var fbAPI = {

    init: function () {
        this.friendList(), this.friendCount();
    },
    friendList: function (closure) {

        var _self = this;

        return FB.api(
            "/me/taggable_friends",
            function (data) {
                _self.setFriends(data);
                closure(data);
            }
        );
    },
    friendCount: function (closure) {

        var _self = this;

        return FB.api(
            "/me/friends",
            function (data) {
                _self.setFriendsCount(data.summary.total_count);
                closure(data);
            }
        );
    },
    friends: null,
    friendsCount: null,
    setFriends: function (data) {
      this.friends = data;
    },
    setFriendsCount: function (count) {
        this.friendsCount = count;
    }
};
```

When all the calls are finished I want to remove the loading overlay.

Something like:

```
 (fbAPI.init()).finish(function(){
     //do something
  });
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should handle all the callbacks.. Maybe try with promises?

Comment: I don't see how without do nested. Think sometime I will have 6 - 7 api calls, and at the end I need to remove the loading.

Comment: Then Promises should do what you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Just tried end did not succed with promise. 

`        init: function (closure) {

            var p1 = new Promise(this.friendList());
            var p2 = new Promise(this.friendCount());

            Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function(a, b){
                closure();
            });

        }, `